# Modificar el DOM con JQUERY de una web extraida con PHP CURL

Tags: jquery, dom, get

Estoy intentando modificar una web extraida en CURL PHP y modificar el DOM con JQUERY pero desaparece parte de la pagina web o obtengo errores cuando Jquery hace su trabajo

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p:contains('Mooc')").text('TextoCambiadoPrueba');
});

</script>




<?php

$ch = curl_init("https://mooc.es/");


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

El codigo a Modificar de la web extraida https://mooc.es/:

```
<p>Los Mooc son <strong>Cursos Online Gratis</strong> de las <strong>mejores universidades del mundo</strong> y que puedes cursar para mejorar en tu trabajo.  Su potencial reside en su capacidad para <strong>conectar el conocimiento de los participantes.</strong></p>
```

al ejecutarse jquery se modifica `Mooc`por`TextoCambiadoPrueba`pero desaparecen estilos css de la web o en este caso todo el texto que falta tal como se muestra en la imagen

mi intencion es extraer una web externa con curl y modificarla con jquery,estoy mirando la alternativa con html_simple_dom_parser.php a ver como funciona

**Pagina Original:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pagina Extraida y Modificada con el codigo expuesto arriba:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se si tiene que ver que varias webs que he probado sean en wordpress y de error la combinacion jquery con php

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente y dónde? Agrega el HTML donde te está fallando.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano el problema es que curl carga la pagina correctamente pero cuando quiero modificar el dom html con jquery me da error,se descuadra parte del html o se eliminan div de la pagina

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y pon el HTML de la página que te está dando problemas, así como las funciones Javascript que actúan sobre ese contenido. Sin ver el terreno problemático poco podemos ayudarte. No vayas a soltar toda una página completa para que la analicemos, muestra el problema localizado diciéndonos: *aquí está el problema, intento hacer esto con este código y lo que ocurre es esto otro*

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado,lo que no se porque tiene conflictos jquery con php a la hora de trabajar juntos

la solucion ha sido con str_replace() de php para editar el dom html,en el caso de **ejemplo del codigo de arriba** lo mejor es eliminar curl y jquery y hacerlo todo con php o `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser`

```
<?php

require "simple_html_dom.php";

$data = file_get_contents("https://mooc.es/"); //or you can use curl too, like me <img src="http://nimishprabhu.com/wp-content/plugins/lazy-load/images/1x1.trans.gif" data-lazy-src="http://nimishprabhu.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/simple-smile.png" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley" style="height: 1em; max-height: 1em;"><noscript><img src="http://nimishprabhu.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/simple-smile.png" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley" style="height: 1em; max-height: 1em;" /></noscript>
    // Some manipulation with the $data variable, for e.g.
$data = str_replace("Los Mooc", "TEXTO CAMBIADO DE PRUEBA", $data);

    //now parsing it into html
$html = str_get_html($data);

echo $html;

?>

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

**lo unico que me gustaria el porque del conflicto de jquery con php como por ejemplo en wordpress que hay que utilizar una funcion para integrar jquery**